# How to split dataframe made out of lists into different columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have the following dataframe. All the content in between the inverted commas are in one column. I want to split them into separate columns.:

```
df=

0,"#1            Microwave Oven Sharp 20 Litres, White, R-20AS-W        5.0 out of 5 stars3SAR 199.00 "
1,"#2            Nikai Microwave - 20 LTR -NMO515N8N        5.0 out of 5 stars3SAR 177.00" 
2,"#3            Geepas 20 Liter Microwave Oven - GMO1894        SAR 186.00"
```

I want to split it into columns like

```
df=
0,"#1",            "Microwave Oven Sharp 20 Litres, White, R-20AS-W",        "5.0 out of 5 stars3", "SAR 199.00 "
    1,"#2",            "Nikai Microwave - 20 LTR -NMO515N8N",        "5.0 out of 5 stars3", "SAR 177.00" 
    2,"#3",            "Geepas 20 Liter Microwave Oven - GMO1894",        "SAR 186.00"
```

Comment: looks like a tab delimited csv, can you add the raw output from the file ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.str.split` with are regex for two more more spaces and parameter `expand=True`:

```
df[column_name].str.split('\s\s+', expand=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

in place of columnname mention your orginal columnname.

```
df["new_col"]=df["columnname"].astype(str).str.split("            ")[0]
df["new_col2"]=df["columnname"].astype(str).str.split("            ")[1]
df["new_col3"]=df["columnname"].astype(str).str.split("            ")[2]
```